# Controlling the grid with `ggeffects::ggpredict`

Tags: r, ggplot2, predict

Suppose I fit a linear model with a continuous predictor that has been categorized. Now I want to make a plot of the mean outcome as a function of the continuous predictor. This would be a staircase function. I could create this manually by specifying a very fine grid and use `stats::predict()`. I'm however interested in whether this is is possible with `ggeffects::ggpredict()`. The plot in the example below suggests that the grid used isn't fine enough. Is there any way to control the grid?

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ cut(wt, c(0,2,4,6)), data = mtcars)
ggpredict(model, c("wt")) |> plot()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface for `ggpredict` is a bit unusual, in that you specify the range and density of the predictor variables inside square brackets as part of the string passed to `terms`. If you set this to, say `"wt [0:6 by=0.01]"`, the predictions should be close enough together to appear as a step function.

Here's a full reprex:

```r
model <- lm(mpg ~ cut(wt, c(0,2,4,6)), data = mtcars)

ggeffects::ggpredict(model, terms = "wt [0:6 by=0.01]") |> plot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Ah, very nice that we're able to pass this to the function! Thanks for the answer.